# Slice single column to two dimensional pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, preprocessor

How do I slice single column to two dimensional pandas DataFrame?

I have singe column time-series data for multiple instruments:

```
DATE        ISIN            ASK
01.05.2017  XS1431271250    0.2401
02.03.2017  XS1431271250    0.2578
01.03.2017  XS1431271250    0.2665
01.05.2017  XS1431274601    0.0474
02.03.2017  XS1431274601    0.0471
01.03.2017  XS1431274601    0.0479
01.05.2017  XS1431271094    0.2419
02.03.2017  XS1431271094    0.2454
01.03.2017  XS1431271094    0.254
```

Instead of it I need single column for each ISIN:

```
Date        XS1431271250    XS1431274601    XS1431271094
01.05.2017  0.2401          0.0474          0.2419
02.03.2017  0.2578          0.0471          0.2454
01.03.2017  0.2665          0.0479          0.254
```

I've tried grouping, df.factorize, df.melt, but did not succeed. 
Please advise the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = df.pivot('DATE','ISIN')
#                    ASK                          
#ISIN       XS1431271094 XS1431271250 XS1431274601
#DATE                                             
#01.03.2017       0.2540       0.2665       0.0479
#01.05.2017       0.2419       0.2401       0.0474
#02.03.2017       0.2454       0.2578       0.0471
```

If you prefer flat column names, you can remove the 'ASK' level:

```
result.columns = result.columns.get_level_values(1)
#ISIN        XS1431271094  XS1431271250  XS1431274601
#DATE                                                
#01.03.2017        0.2540        0.2665        0.0479
#01.05.2017        0.2419        0.2401        0.0474
#02.03.2017        0.2454        0.2578        0.0471
```

Answer (score 0):

This operation is called `pivot`:

```
>>> df.pivot(index='DATE', columns='ISIN')
                ASK                          
ISIN       XS1431271094 XS1431271250 XS1431274601
DATE                                             
01.03.2017       0.2540       0.2665       0.0479
01.05.2017       0.2419       0.2401       0.0474
02.03.2017       0.2454       0.2578       0.0471
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html